# Using an undeclared attribute for jquery event

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code is used to pop up a set of checkboxes that is generated when the radiobox with the value of `Up` is selected.

```
// Experiment
        $("input[name='production-level']").on('change', function() {
            var production = $(this).val();
            var result = '';

            if(production == 'Up') { 
                result  = '<p class="question">Reasons why it is '+ production +'. Click as many as apply.</p>'
                        + '<input type="checkbox" name="production-rsn[]" value="Increase in demand" required>Increase in demand <br/>'
                        + '<input type="checkbox" name="production-rsn[]" value="Expected increase in demand">Expected increase in demand <br/>'
                        + '<input type="checkbox" name="production-rsn[]" value="Fullfillment of past orders">Fulfillment of past orders <br/>'
                        + '<input type="checkbox" name="production-rsn[]" value="Increased marketing activity">Increased marketing activity <br/>'
                        + '<input type="checkbox" name="production-rsn[]" value="other" />Other';    
            } 

            $('#production').html(result);
         });
```

And this code is used to pop up a textbox when the checkbox included in the generated code by the above function with `value="other"` is checked/ticked. The problem is it won't append!

```
$("input[name='production-rsn[]']").on('change', function () {
             var result = '';
             //check if the selected option is others
             if (this.value === "other") {
                 result = '<input id="productionOther" maxlength="30" minlength="3" name="production-other" type="text"/>';
             }

             $('#production').append(result);
        });
```

The problem is the textbox won't append! Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are creating elements dynamically you need to use  [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). You have to use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) using delegated-events approach.

i.e.

```
$(document).on(event, selector, callback_function)
```

Example

```
$('#production').on('change', "input[name='production-rsn[]']", function(){
    //Your code

});
```

In place of `document` you should use closest static container. In your case its `'#production'`

> The delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, we can use delegated events to bind the click event to dynamically created elements and also to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer man. I have one more problem, how do I remove the textbox when the checkbox is not checked anymore?

Comment: @Carnal, You can use `this.checked`, it will return true or false (whether checkbox is checked or not). do changes as per your requirement

Answer (score 1):

Since your `input` elements have been added dynamically to the DOM, all the events will not be available for these newly created `input` until you attach those events to them, you can achieve it using **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**:

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
>   parent element, that will fire for all children matching a selector,
>   whether those children exist now or are added in the future.

```
$('#production').on('change', "input[name='production-rsn[]']", function () {
    var result = '';
    //check if the selected option is others
    if (this.value === "other") {
        result = '<input id="productionOther" maxlength="30" minlength="3" name="production-other" type="text"/>';
    }
    $('#production').append(result);
});
```

Comment: Hey man, I wish I can give 2 right answers but here's a +1 for you answer. :D